# How to check if returned value in an angularjs service is a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm having a lot of trouble guessing how to actually check if the returned value of a function is a promise. I'm using Jasmine with Karma and angularjs. I've made a service:

```
var app = angular.module('myService', []);

function simpleResource ($q) {

   this.cget = function () {
     var deferred = $q.defer();

     return deferred.promise;
   };

   this.get = function () {
     // body...
   };

   this.save = function () {
     // body...
   };

   this.delete = function () {
     // body...
   };
}

app
  .service('nsResource', simpleResource);
```

As you can see, the cget method should return a promise, how can i test that if the returned value is, in fact, a promise?

Comment: Promises have a `then` method, don't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('includeExample', ['ngAnimate'])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$q',
      function($scope, $q) {


        $scope.a = "";
       
        $scope.asyncGreet = function(name) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();

            deferred.notify('About to greet ' + name + '.');
            if (true) {
              deferred.resolve('Hello, ' + name + '!');
            } else {
              deferred.reject('Greeting ' + name + ' is not allowed.');
            }

          return deferred.promise;
        };
        $scope.promise = $scope.asyncGreet('Robin Hood');
        $scope.a = $scope.promise.constructor.name;

       

      }
    ]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-animate.js"></script>

<body ng-app="includeExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <div class="slide-animate-container">
      <span ng-bind="a"><span>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

you can use the `constructor`:

`deferred.promise.constructor == Promise`

Comment: Tryed something similar but Promise is undefined

Comment: you can still use construtor.name will return  a alias for defer() https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L3

Answer (score 1):

You can use $q.when to wrap the object as a promise (whether it is or not). Then, you can be sure that you are always dealing with a promise. This should simplify the code that then handles the result.

Documentation for $q.when is here with $q.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no need to check return value of a function to be promis.

Checking object constructor is very bad idea. Suppose angular developers change promise structure (and its name). So your code is out of date. It is better to use Angular API (which is granted to be stable).

```js
var value = callFunction();
$q.when(value)
.then(function(){
  // doing some thing
});
```

How ever this method is not usable in test.